# Sequential count using 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Using Excel 2013, I would like to make a unique count using 2 columns, like this:

[image: Desired Outcome]

So basically I would like to count each unique function within each name, but:

1. I want it to be sequential, within each name.
2. When the function repeats, within each name, I want it to always have the same value (so if *Compliance* appears 2 times for a given person, I want both to have the same value in both cases (which is 1, in Jim's case).

Is this possible using only formulas in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. Worked for me with your sample data.

`=IFERROR(IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),1,IF(AND(A2=A3,B2=B3),1,1+C1)),1)`

[image]